# Multiple buttons

Tags: buttons

So the scenario:
"The user gets a overview screen and has to do several actions that are required individually from each other to complete a whole process. One can do without the other as well, yet you can do them all and must change them all quickly."

Actions to be taken

1. Confirm selection of people
2. Confirm all people
3. Assign people to event
4. Assign items per person
5. Assign items per company.

All are equally relevant but I don't wanna use 5 primary buttons. Any solutions? :)

Comment: Can you, please, add some more context to each action, e.g. what is the connection between _Confirm selection of people_ vs. _Assign items per company_? How one relates to the other in the whole process?

Comment: Maybe you could use a dropdown and a "send" button. But I don't know if that will fit in your specific UI.

Comment: In addition to @Mike it would be nice if you tell us what solutions you have already tried. Now it looks a lot like: "please do my design".

Comment: post some visual mock showing your efforts as @MatthijsMali has indicated. We need to see your efforts and thinking...

Comment: What's the use case for this? Who will use it, why will they use it, we'll worry about the how in a bit.

Comment: What is the relationship between people, event, person and company? How do they affect each other? This sounds like a homework question.

Comment: Context is important here.

Answer (score 0):

So as per the question, you are asking about a way to show 5 actions which are equally important so that the user can make a judgement without getting biased on anything.

You can use a discoverable action in the form of kebab/meatballs menu where the actions can open in a dropdown or you can use a generic CTA made up of drop-down actions.

Something like this:

[image]